# Socket.io - React : How to retrieve saved socket.io data (MongoDB) in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, socket.io

I followed few tutorials on how to display messages sent in the chatroom before joining in, but I don't know how to display them in React and I have few questions below in the server side.

Client side, in constructor :

```
this.state = {
 msg: "",
 messages: []
};
```

Client side, I have a form which clicked button will send the message to the server by this function :

```
sendMessage(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 let msg = this.state.msg;
 this.socket.emit("sendMessage", msg);
 this.setState({ msg: "" });
}
```

Server side, I have a mongoose Schema for the message, named Message and the collection in the database is messages.

```
const Message = new mongoose.Schema({
 sender: {
  type: "string"
 },
 message: {
  type: "string"
 }
});

var messages = [];

io.on("connection", (socket, user) => {
var user = socket.request.session.user;

Message.find({}).exec((err, messages) => {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log(messages);
 io.emit("showingPastMessages", messages);
});
```

console.log(messages) shows in PowerShell all the messages (entries) saved in Mongo in an array of javascript objects ?
[{id_ : 4qxxx, sender : 'user123', message : 'hello!'}, {id_ : 5exxx, sender : 'user456', message : 'hi!'}]
I would like to know if it is possible to access only to sender and message properties to send it to the client ? Something like messages.sender + messages.message because when I console.log(messages.message) it shows undefined

Here is where the server receives the message sent then saves it in Mongo.

```
socket.on("sendMessage", function(msg) {
var newMsg = new Message({ message: msg, sender: user });
 newMsg.save(function(err) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   } else {
     messages.push(newMsg);
     console.log(newMsg);
     console.log(messages);
   }
 });
});
```

console.log(newMsg) shows the latest msg sent, but the console.log(messages) doesn't show the previous messages but only the latest one, why ?

then in React, I should have something like this in constructor, in ComponentDidMount() ? If should it be with prevState

```
this.socket.on("showingPastMessages", function(messages){
 this.setState({ ...this.state.messages, messages})
});
```

Could you could give me some advices ?

Here my client side code to retrieve the data:

```
class Chat extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  msg: "",
  messages: []
 };

 var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
 this.socket.on("history", function(messages) {
  console.log(messages);
 });
}
```

Comment: You could add the sockets to a room on connection `socket.join('room');` then just emit to the room where you save the message `io.to('room').emit('message', msg);`.  If that's helpful, I'll type up a more thorough answer.

Comment: yes but new joined users wouldn't see the previous messages sent in the chatroom ? I searched up on stackoverflow that storing messages in a database, you could display previous messages even if you weren't in the room. I don't know if I explained well

Comment: I posted a more thorough answer.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good start.  What I would suggest doing is making this a little more event driven.  To do that, you'll want to add the sockets to a room when they connect.  How many rooms and how to split up the rooms will depend on your app, but I'll demonstrate the basic idea.

First, when a socket connects to your server, add that socket to a room and emit your chat history immediately.

```
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  socket.user = socket.request.session.user;

  socket.join('chat');

  try {
    const messages = await Message.find({});

    socket.emit('history', messages);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle this error properly.
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Then, later on, when you receive a message, you'll want to save that message and emit it to all of the sockets in your chat room.

```
socket.on("sendMessage", (msg, callback) => {
  const message = new Message({ message: msg, sender: socket.user });

  message.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    io.to('chat').emit('message', message);
  });
});
```

Finally, on the client side, you'll want to listen for the history event.  When you receive it, you'll want to clear the chat history you currently have and replace it with what the server is telling you.  Maybe this would look something like

```
socket.on('history', (messages) => {
  this.setState({ messages });
});
```

You'll also want to listen for this `message` event, but with this event, you'll only append the message to your history.  This might look something like

```
socket.on('message', (message) => {
  this.setState({ messages: [ ...messages, message ] });
});
```

A word of warning, if when you tell the server about a new message, do not add it to your `messages` state array until you receive the `message` event.  If you do so, you will notice double messages.  For example, this might look something like

```
onSendMessage(evnt) {
  evnt.preventDefault();

   socket.emit("sendMessage", msg);
   this.setState({ msg: "" });
}
```

**Note**: After receiving some feedback from the OP, I wanted to add a section on where to put the event handlers attached to the socket (i.e. all the `socket.on`s).  My suggestion would be to add this code in the file that defines the `Message` schema at the bottom of the file in the `io.on('connection')` callback.  For example,

```
const Message = new mongoose.Schema({/*...*/});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // Everything else I wrote above...

  socket.on('sendMessage', (msg, callback) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

On the client side, the event handlers would probably be registered when the chat component is mounted.  For example,

```
class ChatComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('https://your-server-or-localhost/');

    this.socket.on('history', (messages) => {
      // See above...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have few questions about your code, what is const messages = Message.find({}) ? it should be an array of objects, can you just send it like this to the client? where would you put the socket.on, in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, I made a few typos.  `const messages = Message.find({})` should be (const messages = await Message.find({});`, which will return an array of all the messages you have saved so far.  Yes you should be able to send it like that to the client.

Comment: Where you put the `socket.on` can depend on your app; however, based on your example, you would put it in `io.on('connection', (socket) => {});` in the same file you defined your Message schema.

Comment: I understand it ! But my problem is how can I display the messages immediately when page is loaded ? I have a chatroom in the page, and I would like the previous messages to be there when page is loaded. Where would I write the client side socket.on("history", ...) ?

Comment: It kinda depends on you set up, but probably in the same place you establish your socket connection or when the component mounts. Since the event is fired immediately after connecting, it'll have to be something already listening by the time the socket connection is complete.

Comment: I did write in the constructor (where I set up the socket client) and I tried to console.log(messages) but nothing in the inspector.. normally I would see the array of all the previous messages right? I also tried in componentDidMount but nothing in the inspector too

Comment: Do you have a repo or code snippet that you can share?  Look in the network tab of your browser's debugger and see what messages you're receiving.

Comment: yes by inspector I meant the debugger, and I don't receive anything, but in powershell I have the array of the previous messages, so in server side it is ok, only in the client side I can't see the data received, if you could see the last part of code that I added in my question, where did I do wrong?

Comment: tried with your client side code, with the componentDidMount, and it doesn't show anything in the debugger when I try to console.log(messages)

Comment: In the code you posted, you create a new variable for the socket `var socket`, but you refer to that new variable on `this`.  Either use the variable you defined `socket.on` (instead of `this.socket.on`) or put `socket` on `this` (`this.socket = io('...');`).

Comment: This conversation is getting a little long.  If you need further help, let's move this conversation to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189239/socket-io-react-how-to-retrieve-saved-socket-io-data-mongodb-in-react).

Comment: socket.emit("history", ...) cannot be directly called when we call the socket connection, it must be in a socket.on("something", ...), and I just put the code in the constructor instead of a componentDidMount, so now my console.log in the client shows the messages from the database! and I can display them as you suggested. Everything works! Thank you again for your help :)